# JPA and enum type

Tags: java, caching, jpa

I use for an JPA entity one field of enum type :

```
@Enumerated(value=EnumType.STRING)
private Temperament temperament = Temperament.MINEUR_PUR;
```

My enum is declared inside my entity :

```
@Entity
public class Joueur implements Serializable {

.....

    public enum Temperament{
        MINEUR_PUR(30),
        MINEUR(10),
        NEUTRE(0),
        RAIDEUR(-10),
        RAIDEUR_PUR(-30);

        private int temperament_prod_mines;

        private Temperament(int temperament_prod_mines){
            this.temperament_prod_mines = temperament_prod_mines;       
        }

        public int getTemperament_prod_mines() {
            return temperament_prod_mines;
        }

        public void setTemperament_prod_mines(int temperament_prod_mines) {
            this.temperament_prod_mines = temperament_prod_mines;
        }
    }   
}
```

it's work but when I "externalize" my enum in it's own file, it doesn't work anymore :

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7151] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: The type [class com.sim.basics.enums.Temperament] for the attribute [temperament] on the entity class [class com.sim.entities.Joueur] is not a valid type for an enumerated mapping. The attribute must be defined as a Java enum.

but it's just a copy/paste...

Why this behaviour ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you put the enum in a separate lib.jar?

Comment: it is indeed. It is packaged with maven in an EAR and my entity and its enum type aren't in same JAR. I am going to test inside same JAR. Thanks for this idea

Comment: I ended up with the exact same symptoms when the .jar including the enums was not visible for the entities

Comment: It was the cause of the problem, when I move my enum in same JAR as my entities, it's work...Is there a workaround to keep my enum outside entities JAR ? Ty

Comment: in meta-inf/manifest of entity.jar i had to add classpath: enum.jar. bit diirty but dont know another way. ill add a proper answer when not on pppphone

Comment: thx for quickly answers, I will test that

Comment: OMG ! Didn't realize that I forgot to include my enum JAR in EAR with Maven ! I use provided scopes because I include all my JARs with jarModule block inside maven-ear-plugin. So in compile time, no worries but at runtime, my JAR was missing. For me no needs to modify class-path in Manifest. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cause of this problem is that the enumeration defined in enum.jar is in runtime not found on the classpath by the entity.

There are atleast two ways to solve this.

1. In META-INF/MANIFEST.MH of entity.jar

   classpath: enum.jar
2. Or to specify the enum.jar as part of the EAR if you use maven.

Answer (score 0):

This **[EclipseLink Exception Error Reference (ELUG)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink_Exception_Error_Reference_%28ELUG%29)** may help you

### **ECLIPSELINK-07151: The type [{1}] for the attribute [{0}] on the entity class [{2}] is not a valid type for an enumerated mapping. The attribute must be defined as a Java enum.**

**Cause:** An invalid EJB 3.0 annotation annotation has been specified in the entity class ClassName on accessor method methodName. It is not supported.

**Action:** Specify a valid annotation on this accessor method.